# Convert x digit random number to varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, data-conversion

I am creating a 14 digit random number in SQL Server 2008 R2 using the following query:

```
select FLOOR(RAND() * POWER(CAST(10 as BIGINT), 14))
```

Now I need to convert this number into varchar for which I use this query:

```
select 
    convert(varchar(50), FLOOR(RAND() * POWER(CAST(10 as BIGINT), 14)))
```

It convert the number but in `6.74151e+013` form.

So I tried this:

```
select 
    convert(varchar(50), FLOOR(RAND() * POWER(CAST(10 as BIGINT), 5))) +
    convert(varchar(50), FLOOR(RAND() * POWER(CAST(10 as BIGINT), 5))) + 
    convert(varchar(50), FLOOR(RAND() * POWER(CAST(10 as BIGINT), 4)))
```

It does create a 14 digit varchar but I feel there can be a shorter way to do so. I have tried various other ways too but they return the answer in the `6.74151e+013` format which I cannot use.

Please help.

EDIT: If there is another way of creating a 14 digit random numeric string directly(i.e. without using rand()) then do tell that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`, because it allows to specify how many random bytes you need.

Then, since you need decimal digits, not hexadecimal, cast result to `bigint`;
then convert it to `varchar` and take last 14 digits:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CAST(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) AS bigint) AS varchar(50)), 14)
```

This can be simplified to:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) AS bigint), 14)
```

because `RIGHT` converts `bigint` into `varchar` implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `FLOOR()`, convert to a `DECIMAL`:

```
select CONVERT(DECIMAL(14, 0), RAND() * POWER(CAST(10 as BIGINT), 14))
```

Then convert this to a varchar:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), 
               CONVERT(DECIMAL(14, 0), RAND() * POWER(CAST(10 as BIGINT), 14))
              )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(14),CONVERT(BIGINT,FLOOR(RAND() * POWER(CAST(10 as BIGINT), 14))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check This.

Using NEWID() .

```
    select cast(RIGHT(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(36)) AS BIGINT), 14) as varchar(50))
```

OR
Using rand()

```
      select convert(varchar(50),convert(numeric(14,0),rand() * 89999999999999))
```